# Скопировать нужные XElement'ы и ничего лишнего

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Подскажите, есть ли штатные средства в C#, чтобы я мог передав какой-нибудь XPath, скопировать всю иерархию с атрибутами, значениями и ничего лишнего.

Скажем, передаю такой XPath: root/TableRow/Id

и пусть там помимо TableRow в root'е есть другие узлы, он их не возьмет.

Или нужно самому ручками все обходить, начиная с последнего элемента и строить свою копию по-узлам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, прямо в лоб такого нету, но можно сделать не сильно напрягаясь.

Пример:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
  <Table Name="First">
    <TableRow>
      <id>1</id>
      <age>20</age>
      <name>John</name>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
      <id>2</id>
      <age>21</age>
      <name>Johann</name>
    </TableRow>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="Second">
    <TableRow>
      <id>3</id>
      <age>22</age>
      <name>Jean</name>
    </TableRow>
  </Table>
  <NotTable Name="Third">
    <TableRow>
      <id>4</id>
      <age>23</age>
      <name>Giovanni</name>
    </TableRow>
  </NotTable>
</Root>
```

Вот такой код:

```cs
XDocument doc = ...
var clone = new XDocument(doc); // deep clone
var selectedElements =
    clone.XPathSelectElements("/Root//TableRow/id") // выберем те элементы, которые нужно
         .AncestorsAndSelf() // и их предков
         .ToHashSet();       // и соберём в множество для эффективного поиска
// остальные удалим
clone.Descendants().Where(d => !selectedElements.Contains(d)).Remove();
```

производит такой XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
  <Table Name="First">
    <TableRow>
      <id>1</id>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
      <id>2</id>
    </TableRow>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="Second">
    <TableRow>
      <id>3</id>
    </TableRow>
  </Table>
</Root>
```

---

Возможно, более правильное решение — [использовать XSLT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/use-xslt-transform-xml-tree) (но я его не знаю).

Comment: Да, отлично работает. Благодарю.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Не за что!